# Stop SWF autoplay in html

Tags: html, flash, autoplay

How to stop auto-play of the SWF file while embedding in html.
Here is the code that I am using:
    `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="videos/xxx-xxx-xxx.swf" width="100%" height="100%" style="undefined" id="Captivate" name="Captivate" bgcolor="#333333" quality="high" wmode="window" seamlesstabbing="false" menu="false" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="variable1=value1">`

Answer (score 0):

Just add ?autoplay=0 after url in embed code and let me know.

Comment: Tried this. Not working. It is not stopping autoplay.

Comment: Tried ?autoplay=0 also but not working.

is there any chances of having settings while creating SWF?

Answer (score 0):

If changing autoplay on the embed code doesn't work, you could try adding this to your flash movie:

1. Create a new layer in your timeline and call it "actions"
2. Select the first frame of that layer, and press F9 to open the Actions editor.
3. Type in the following code: `stop();`

When you play the movie, it should no longer autoplay.

Answer (score -1):

Look for `<param name="play" value="false" />` or in `embed` add `play="false"`
This parameters stop on Main Timeline in 1st frame